# I'm trying to get my memory functions to work on a C# calculator

Tags: c#, calculator

This is my code up to this point, As you might see i am quite new to coding and this code just won't work. Really looking for some help or tips.
The memory functions just show a 0 if clicked and it isn't working at all.
all the rest of these functions work as planned.
Edit: I have updated the code. There seems to be some trouble with the decimal and double.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Double ResultaatWaarde = 0;
    decimal EindResult = 0;
    decimal MemoryStore = 0;
    string FunctieVoltooid = "";
    bool isFunctieVoltooid = false;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TopMost = true;
    }

    // Nummers /. Getalen 
    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((textBox_Resultaat.Text == "0") || (isFunctieVoltooid))
            textBox_Resultaat.Clear();

         isFunctieVoltooid = false;

        Button button = (Button)sender;
        if(button.Text == ",")
        {
            if (!textBox_Resultaat.Text.Contains(",")) 
            textBox_Resultaat.Text = textBox_Resultaat.Text + button.Text;
        }
        else
        textBox_Resultaat.Text = textBox_Resultaat.Text + button.Text;
    }

    // Functies
    private void Functie_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button button = (Button)sender;

        if (ResultaatWaarde != 0)
        {

            buttonIS.PerformClick();
            FunctieVoltooid = button.Text;
            HuidigeProcess.Text = ResultaatWaarde + " " + FunctieVoltooid;
            isFunctieVoltooid = true;

        }
        else
        {

            FunctieVoltooid = button.Text;
            ResultaatWaarde = Double.Parse(textBox_Resultaat.Text);
            HuidigeProcess.Text = ResultaatWaarde + " " + FunctieVoltooid;
            isFunctieVoltooid = true;

        }

    }

    //Clear Entries knop
    private void buttonClearEntries_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox_Resultaat.Text = "0";

    }

    // Clear Knop
    private void buttonClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox_Resultaat.Text = "0";
        ResultaatWaarde = 0;
        HuidigeProcess.Text = "";
    }

    // = Knop
    private void buttonIS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        switch(FunctieVoltooid)
        {
            case "+":
                textBox_Resultaat.Text = (ResultaatWaarde + Double.Parse(textBox_Resultaat.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "-":
                textBox_Resultaat.Text = (ResultaatWaarde - Double.Parse(textBox_Resultaat.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "*":
                textBox_Resultaat.Text = (ResultaatWaarde * Double.Parse(textBox_Resultaat.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "/":
                textBox_Resultaat.Text = (ResultaatWaarde / Double.Parse(textBox_Resultaat.Text)).ToString();
                break;
            case "x²":
                textBox_Resultaat.Text = (ResultaatWaarde * ResultaatWaarde).ToString();
                break;
            case " √":
                textBox_Resultaat.Text = (Math.Sqrt(double.Parse(textBox_Resultaat.Text))).ToString();
                break;
            case "1/x":
                textBox_Resultaat.Text = (1 / ResultaatWaarde).ToString();
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
        ResultaatWaarde = Double.Parse(textBox_Resultaat.Text);
        HuidigeProcess.Text = "";

    }

    // Memory knoppen
    private void memory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button gedruktebutton = (Button)sender;
        string ButtonText = gedruktebutton.Text;


        if (ButtonText == "MC")
        {
            //Memory Clear
            MemoryStore = 0;
            return;
        }

        if (ButtonText == "MR")
        {
            //Memory Recall
            txtDisplay.Text = MemoryStore.ToString();
            return;
        }
        if (ButtonText == "MS")
        {
            MemoryStore = Decimal.Parse(txtDisplay.Text);
            return;
        }

        if (ButtonText == "M-")
        {
            // Memory subtract
            MemoryStore = ResultaatWaarde;
            MemoryStore -= EindResult;
            txtDisplay.Text = MemoryStore.ToString();
            return;
        }

        if (ButtonText == "M+")
        {
            // Memory add 

            MemoryStore += EindResult;
            txtDisplay.Text = MemoryStore.ToString();
            return;

        }

    }

    private void textBox_Resultaat_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `MemoryStore` and `EindResult` have been declared as local variables (inside the function memory_Click). This function (based on the name) gets called every time you press the Memory buttons, and every time you press them, the first thing that happens is:

```
decimal EindResult = 0;
decimal MemoryStore = 0;
```

So basically, although you may store the value based on the button presses, when you next call the code, all of that is first zeroed out.  One way of fixing this would be to move `EindResult` and `MemoryStore` to the class level (under where `ResultaatWaarde` is declared). This way, the values will survive so long as the Form is active.

Comment: Thank you this is a big help!! however my buttons still don't seem to get any value out of the textbox. and whenever i try to recall the memory there is just another zero.

Comment: @Bartoes - Please edit your question and provide your updated code.  Also, where is `EindResult` being set?

Comment: Thank you, i have updated the code and i now see that i have indeed not set ---EindResult--.

Comment: The issue has been resolved, I want to thank all of you who helped me! :)

Comment: Just a suggestion:  Instead of having a single function for all of the buttons and then using a bunch of "If" statements, it would be easier to read (and slightly more efficient) if each button had it's own function.  That way, your code has a strong self-commenting element.  If someone else ever has to look at your code, then each button is executing it's own self-contained function with a name that reflects where it's being called from (assuming that you are naming your buttons using names that reflect their functionality).